# Как в адресном строке вывести имя продукта [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

У меня сейчас реализована таким образам:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ProductList", "Product", new { id = Model.ProductID })'>
```

принимающий метод:

```
public ActionResult ProductList(int id = 0)
    {
        var item = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == id);
        return View(item);
    }
```

В этом случаи в адресном строке показываться к примеру так 
"imyasayta.ru/**id2**"

Хочу сделать что бы имя продукта показывала в место id.
Если сделаю таким образам:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ProductList", "Product", new { name = Model.Name, })'>
```

и метод

```
public ActionResult ProductList(string name)
    {
        var item = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        return View(item);
    }
```

то у меня конфликтует с сортировкой продуктов, сортировка тоже принимает string

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Product",
            url: "id{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductList" }
        );
routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
        );
```

Как вывести имя продукта но в методе получить id?

Решил посмотреть исходник NopCommerce (там так и происходит)

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName })" title="@Model.DefaultPictureModel.Title">
```

принимающий метод

```
public ActionResult ProductDetails(int productId, int updatecartitemid = 0)
    {
        ....
        return View(model.ProductTemplateViewPath, model);
    }
```

но это не возможно же
Как такого достичь? заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Я не совсем пойму, что ты имеешь ввиду под `конфликтует с сортировкой продуктов`?

Comment: в "RouteConfig.cs" вторая MapRoute для сортировки продуктов по категории. Когда нажимаю на ссылки с сортировками он идет по первому MapRoute. Одним словом не могу обе разделить по разным MapRoute.

Comment: Мне надо, к примеру "sayt.ru/ImyaProdukta" и "sayt.ru/SortirovkaPoKolichestvu" распределялись по разным MapRoute-ам

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю: зачем для такой задачи лесть в `маршрутизацию`? Я думал тебе для безопасности надо скрыть `id`.

Comment: Ну скрывать тоже нужно и для красоты. А как делать то если не машрутизация?